# Change database owner of Azure SQL Database

Tags: permissions, azure-sql-database, owner

I want to change the database owner of an Azure SQL Database. I can do this via the server administration user. However I want to do it using a different user. Why? Because I have a process which copies a database from one server to another using a specific user account that is not the server administration user, and I need this user to be able to set the db owner after the copy completes.

Here's the deal.

I've an Azure SQL Database **database1** owned by **user1**. I want to change the database owner to **user2**. Both users are SQL authentication logins.

Running the below query from the master database, I can see the user who owns database1 is user1 with SID 0x01060000000000640000000000000000F67524E3236132449A7483D4456F051E.

```
SELECT d.name, d.owner_sid, sl.name
FROM sys.databases AS d
JOIN sys.sql_logins AS sl
ON d.owner_sid = sl.sid;
```

I login to database1 with user1. Running the below query, I can see my SID is 0x01060000000000640000000000000000F67524E3236132449A7483D4456F051E

```
SELECT USER_SID()
```

Logged in to database1 as user1, I run the query below, from the context of database1 (target database), to update the database owner, and I get the error "User does not have permission to perform this action.".

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::database1 TO [user2];
```

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#alter-authorization-for-databases), the conditions for changing an Azure SQL Database owner are:

- The new owner principal can be a SQL Server authentication login.
- The person executing the ALTER AUTHORIZATION statement must be connected to the target database.
- The person changing the owner of a database can be the current owner of the database.

So I am unsure what I've missed, but I would like to know why I am unable to change the database owner.

Comment: Which user are you running the `ALTER AUTHORIZATION` statement as? If you're running as User2, ensure it has the TAKE OWNERSHIP permission on the database. If you're running as another user, ensure that user has IMPERSONATE permission on User2

Comment: Running it as user1, the database owner.

Comment: You need to confirm if user1 has IMPERSONATE permissions on user2 - if not, then that is likely why it isn't working

Comment: user1, being the database owner, has IMPERSONATE permissions. The database owner has CONTROL permission which includes IMPERSONATE. I also confirmed this by impersonating the user via EXECUTE AS.